# How do I dynamically create a struct for a stack in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, dereference

I am working on a stack program for a C++ program. I have isEmpty, peek, and pop mostly finished but I'm trying to figure out some things that are unique to C++ after taking Java last semester. For this program, we are creating a stack of pointers to an ADT struct called Data which has two attributes (an int called id and a string called data).

For push(), the professors asks us to "dynamically create a struct" to hold the values of the Data struct that was pushed. I generally understand dynamic memory allocation as it pertains to ArrayLists in Java so I know that he is asking us to create structs as needed, but I'm struggling to put the pieces together. Say I have a variable in push() called pushData that is a Data struct. When I call push(), I assign pushData's attributes using the values passed to push, and add a pointer to pushData onto the stack.

My initial thought was to create a parallel array as part of Stack which could hold the values of each Data struct pushed onto the stack and that array of structs could be parallel to the array/stack of pointers. While I think this would work, there must be another way because the professor has said that we cannot modify Stack's attributes, meaning I could not create a parallel array to hold the values. Dynamically sized arrays are the only way I remember past professors teaching the concept of dynamically allocating memory, so I'm not sure how to incorporate it into this specific scenario.

If that is not the solution, then I do not know the best way to hold onto each Data struct's value after it's pushed. My assumption is that when each call to push finishes, the pushData struct would be deleted and then push() would re-create the pushData variable and give it a new value each time it's called again...

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give. I am frustrated with myself for getting this far to feel very stuck on the last method. Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help.

We have been given:

```
struct Data 
{ 
    int id; 
    string data; 
};

class Stack 
{ 
    public: 
    /* 
     * write all your public method prototypes here 
     */ 
    private: 
    /* write all your private method prototypes here */ 
    // these are the only attributes you need. do not modify them or add any 
    int top; // this is your top index 
    Data *stack[STACK_SIZE]; // this is your stack, it is an array of Data pointers 
};
```

Comment: Sounds more like C but if it's C++ I would imitate the interface of std::stack. Does your struct have a copy constructor (or is PoD type)? If you want to manually use new/delete, then you'll have to track those pointers.

Comment: "The best way" would be to use `<stack>`. Making students reimplement the standard library (badly) by hamstringing them into *not* using the standard library is really doing everyone a disservice. You never should have to implement basic data structures yourself, *especially* not ones where you dynamically allocate memory. That's what the standard library is *for*, and what you *should* be taught...

Comment: @DevSolar, I'm sure there are situations where it's important to know how to implement a `stack` and there are situations where it's only important to know how to just use one.

Comment: What does the code your professor's given you look like?

Comment: So, the professor gave us the stack.h file which looked like this:

class Stack {

public:
     /* 
     * write all your public method prototypes here
     */
    
private:

    /* 
     * write all your private method prototypes here
     */

    // these are the only attributes you need. do not modify them or add any
    int top; // this is your top index
    Data *stack[STACK_SIZE]; // this is your stack, it is an array of Data pointers
};

Comment: And also the ADT Data struct: 
struct Data {
    int id;
    string data;
};

Comment: @RSahu: I strongly dispute that "how to implement a stack" is material for a C++ beginner's course. **Not** having to implement basic data structures **because** there's a strong standard library to draw upon is one of the core features of C++. Knowing, *trusting* those standard containers is important. Opening the hood too early has been hurting the C++ developer pool for far too long. "C++ is hard" only because of bad courses like this one. I have yet to see a Java course that shows how to *implement* `ArrayList` as opposed to just *using* it. You end up with people distrusting `<vector>`...

Comment: A reality note: The instructor probably added the requirement for dynamic memory to up the difficulty level and get you suffering through `new` and `delete` early. In the real world no one sane and more than passably familiar with C++ writes code like this. `new` and `delete` are only pulled out of the toolbox when all other alternatives have been exhausted. There are a LOT of alternatives. in this case, plain old `Data stack[STACK_SIZE];` does everything you need. `Data[top++] = Data(number, "string");` does everything you need when adding. To remove, `top--;`. Done.

Comment: @DevSolar Every programmer should learn how to implement some basic data structures. You're in college to learn how to fish, not which fisihing rod to use.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne As I said, compare the approach by far too many C++ courses with your average Java or Python course. Too much 1970's mindset going on there, leading to C++ still having that reputation of being complicated, when really it is quite the opposite. Teach 'em what each structure is, where to find them, and how to **use** them. I disagree that practice with implementing them is useful at that level. Also, homegrown structures usually do not play well with `<algorithm>` either...

Answer (score 0):

i guess for learning, its fine.

For a stack, usually an array is created on creation of the stack. Usually this is the only dynamic allocation of memory.

when copying of data theres no need to create new memory for it. in C++ its important to understand the copy and move semantics, the difference between l-values , r-values and x-values.

in the case of the string in the data structure, do keep in mind of shallow copy.

with that understood and some pointer arithmetic , you should be able to finish your assignment

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can dynamically create struct objects

```
struct Square
{
    double side;
};

struct Rectangle
{
    double length, width;
};

vector<void*> myBag; //This allows you to have a vector (ArrayList/List) of any type 
vector<int> bagTracker; // 0: square, 1: rectangle we need a companion vector to track down the type of the objects pushed into the vector

Square *square
square = new Square;
square->side = num1;

myBag.push_back(square);
bagTracker.push_back(0);

Rectangle *rectangle
rectangle = new Rectangle;
rectangle->length = num1;
rectangle->width = num2;
                
myBag.push_back(rectangle);
bagTracker.push_back(1);
```

In order to access to the objects you need to `reinterpret_cast` to typecast any pointer to any other data type

```
Square *square = reinterpret_cast<Square*>(myBag.at(i));
cout << square->side << endl;
```

Same applies for using functions

```
Square *square = reinterpret_cast<Square*>(myBag.at(i));
outputSquare(cout, *square);
```

Hope this answers or helps

EDIT

I forgot to declare `Square *square` and `Rectangle *rectangle`

For deleting

```
Square *square = reinterpret_cast<Square*>(myBag.at(i));
delete square;
```

Comment: You don't `delete` what you `new`. That will cause a memory leak in the future.

Comment: At this point I'd start talking about `unique_ptr`, but with the instructor apparently disallowing the standard library, that might not be an option either. :-(

Comment: I haven't used vectors before so I would need to familiarize myself with them to better understand this solution. Also, we are not allowed to modify the struct's attributes so I couldn't change them to vectors anyway. Seeing you use the new keyword drummed up some memory of dynamic memory allocation from last fall semester when I took my first c++ class, but when I tried to use it in my program I was getting a lot of errors I'm still trying to understand. Will post errors in a separate comment.

Comment: I tried "pushData = new Data(idPushed, dataPushed);" and received this error message: stack.cpp: In member function ‘bool Stack::push(int, std::string)’:
stack.cpp:74:4: error: ‘pushData’ was not declared in this scope
   74 |    pushData = new Data(idPushed, dataPushed);
      |    ^~~~~~~~
stack.cpp:74:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘Data::Data(int&, std::string&)’
   74 |    pushData = new Data(idPushed, dataPushed);
      |                                            ^
In file included from stack.h:14,
                 from stack.cpp:10:

Comment: Continued: data.h:21:8: note: candidate: ‘Data::Data()’
   21 | struct Data {
      |        ^~~~
data.h:21:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
data.h:21:8: note: candidate: ‘Data::Data(const Data&)’
data.h:21:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
data.h:21:8: note: candidate: ‘Data::Data(Data&&)’
data.h:21:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided